# Querydsl 4 StringExpression of a field inside a SimplePath

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

I have an `Order` entity which contains a `OrderCustomer` field and `OrderCustomer` entity has an `Customer` field.

```
@Document
public class Order {
    private OrderCustomer orderCustomer;
}

public class OrderCustomer {
    private Customer customer;
}

public class Customer {
    private String referenceNumber;
}
```

And the query class generated by `org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor` looks like:

```
public QOrder {
    public final QOrderCustomer orderCustomer;
}

public QOrderCustomer {
    public final SimplePath<Customer> = createSimple("customer", Customer.class);
}
```

In this case, how can I create a predicate to check `Customer.referenceNumber` contains any string input from client?

For example:
`QOrder.order.orderCustomer.customer.referenceNumber.contains("anystring")`

Or maybe the code is not generated properly? Should generate QCustomer?

My dependency versions:
querydsl 4.1.4
+
spring-data-mongodb 1.9.5 (managed by spring-data-releasetrain:Hopper-SR5)

Answer (score 7):

To generate `QCustomer`, I have to put `@QueryEmbeddable` on `Customer` type. Not sure this is a correct solution.

Comment: I had the same issue, it didn't generate the `QMyClass` but instead `SimplePath<MyClass>`, when I added the `@QueryEmbeddable` annotation, it worked as expected!

Comment: for my case it was `@QueryEmbedded`

Comment: Can anyone explain what @QueryEmbedded do. I am bit confused with document. Thanks