# Q class not generating by query-dsl for nested embedded objects inside document class in spring data

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

I have below collection and embedded documents

```
    @Data
    @Builder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @Document(collection = "person_details")
    public class PersonDetails {
    
        @MongoId(FieldType.OBJECT_ID)
        private String managerId;
        .
        .
        @QueryInit("addressDetails.*")
        private List<ContactDetails> contactDetails;
        .
 }
```

And ContactDetails.java looks like below:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ContactDetails {
    private AddressDetails addressDetails;
   
    private StateDetails stateDetails;
}
```

StateDetails look like below:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Document(collection = "statedetails")
public class StateDetails {
    @MongoId(FieldType.OBJECT_ID)
    private String stateId;
    private String stateName;
}
```

And AddressDetails look like below:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class AddressDetails {
    private String address;
    @Field(targetType = FieldType.STRING)
    private AddressTypeEnum addressType;
}
```

After building , I am not getting Q class for AddressDetails, due to which I am facing issues in building Predicate. Below is my generated QPersonDetail class

```
@Generated("com.querydsl.codegen.DefaultEntitySerializer")
public class QPersonDetails extends EntityPathBase<PersonDetails> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 184263140L;

    private static final PathInits INITS = new PathInits("*", "contactDetails.addressDetails.*");

    public static final QPersonDetails managerDetails = new QPersonDetails("managerDetails");

   
    public final ListPath<ContactDetails, QContactDetails> contactDetails = this.<ContactDetails, QContactDetails>createList("contactDetails", ContactDetails.class, QContactDetails.class, INITS.get("contactDetails"));

    
    public QPersonDetails(String variable) {
        this(PersonDetails.class, forVariable(variable), INITS);
    }

    public QPersonDetails(Path<? extends PersonDetails> path) {
        this(path.getType(), path.getMetadata(), PathInits.getFor(path.getMetadata(), INITS));
    }

    public QPersonDetails(PathMetadata metadata) {
        this(metadata, PathInits.getFor(metadata, INITS));
    }

    public QPersonDetails(PathMetadata metadata, PathInits inits) {
        this(PersonDetails.class, metadata, inits);
    }
}
```

And below is generated QContactDetails:

```
@Generated("com.querydsl.codegen.DefaultEmbeddableSerializer")
public class QContactDetails extends BeanPath<ContactDetails> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1039545873L;

    private static final PathInits INITS = PathInits.DIRECT2;

    public static final QContactDetails contactDetails = new QContactDetails("contactDetails");

    public final SimplePath<AddressDetails> addressDetails = createSimple("addressDetails", AddressDetails.class);

   
    public QContactDetails(String variable) {
        this(ContactDetails.class, forVariable(variable), INITS);
    }

    public QContactDetails(Path<? extends ContactDetails> path) {
        this(path.getType(), path.getMetadata(), PathInits.getFor(path.getMetadata(), INITS));
    }

    public QContactDetails(PathMetadata metadata) {
        this(metadata, PathInits.getFor(metadata, INITS));
    }

    public QContactDetails(PathMetadata metadata, PathInits inits) {
        this(ContactDetails.class, metadata, inits);
    }
}
```

I referred many threads including
https://querydsl.com/static/querydsl/5.0.0/reference/html/ch03s03.html but still not able to figure out issue. Even i tried with

```
@QueryInit("*.*")
```

annotation on contactDetails, above. Any idea, where I am missing. I dont want AddressDetails to be annotated as @Document.

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread [Querydsl 4 StringExpression of a field inside a SimplePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391206/querydsl-4-stringexpression-of-a-field-inside-a-simplepath)
This solves theproblem, but I am still confused with the concept, how @QueryEmbeddable works